# While reading and writing xml file using LINQ to XML I am facing "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq-to-xml

While reading and writing xml file using LINQ to XML I am facing "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process"

### Exception log is

> 9/25/2014 4:49:03 PM Exception: Class Common, Method Name: CreateXML.
>   ExceptionThe process cannot access the file 'D:\Program Files\Default
>   Company Name\Setup\Settings\Settings.xml' because it is being used by
>   another process.

Please suggest some way.

Below is my code:

```
public void CreateXML(string toEmail, out int notificationCount, out string email, bool IsFirstTime = false)
{
    notificationCount = 0;
    email = string.Empty;
    try
    {

        string path = String.Format(@"{0}Settings", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
        string filePath = path + "\\Settings.xml";
        if (!Directory.Exists(path)) Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        if (!IsFirstTime)
        {
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
                if (xmlDoc.Elements("Filters").Count() > 0)
                {

                    XElement doc = new XElement(
                                                  new XElement("Filter",
                                                      new XElement("ToEmail", toEmail),
                                                      new XElement("Date", DateTime.Now.ToString())
                                                      )
                                                  );
                    xmlDoc.Element("Filters").Add(doc);
                    try
                    {
                        xmlDoc.Save(filePath);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        string x = ex.Message;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    CreateXmlNodes(toEmail, filePath);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                CreateXmlNodes(toEmail, filePath);
            }
        }
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(filePath);
            notificationCount = GetEmailAndNotificationCount(notificationCount, filePath, xmlDoc, out email);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        new Logging().LogException("Class Common, Method Name: CreateXML. Exception" + ex.Message);
    }
}

private static int GetEmailAndNotificationCount(int notificationCount, string filePath, XDocument xmlDoc, out string email)
{
    email = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        XElement xdoc = XElement.Load(filePath);
        if (xdoc.Elements("Filter").Count() > 0)
        {
            var data = (from p in xdoc.Descendants("Date").Where(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.Value) > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
                        select p).ToList().Count;
            NotificationCount = notificationCount = data;

            var emails = (from p in xdoc.Descendants("Filter").Where(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.Element("Date").Value) > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
                          select p.Element("ToEmail").Value).Distinct().Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Convert.ToString(x))).ToList();
            if (emails.Count > 0)
            {
                emails.ForEach(x => sb.Append(x.ToString()).Append("\n"));
            }
            EmailsToDisplay = email = sb.ToString();
            xmlDoc.Descendants("Filter").Where(x => Convert.ToDateTime(x.Element("Date").Value) < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2)).Remove();
            try
            {
                xmlDoc.Save(filePath);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                new Logging().LogException("Class Common, Method Name: GetEmailAndNotificationCount. Exception" + ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        new Logging().LogException("Class Common, Method Name: GetEmailAndNotificationCount. Exception" + ex.Message);
        email = string.Empty;
        return 0;
    }

    return notificationCount;
}

private static void CreateXmlNodes(string toEmail, string filePath)
{
    XDocument doc = new XDocument(
                                  new XElement("Filters",
                                    new XElement("Filter",
                                        new XElement("ToEmail", toEmail),
                                        new XElement("Date", DateTime.Now.ToString())
                                        )
                                    ));
    try
    {
        doc.Save(filePath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        new Logging().LogException("Class Common, Method Name: CreateXmlNodes. Exception" + ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Stack Trace :

```
"StackTrace:at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost) at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role,Type ofObjectToReturn)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.FinishInitUriString()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl..ctor(String uriStr, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext context, XmlResolver uriResolver)
   at System.Xml.XmlReaderSettings.CreateReader(String inputUri, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   at System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(String inputUri, XmlReaderSettings settings, XmlParserContext inputContext)
   at System.Xml.Linq.XDocument.Load(String uri, LoadOptions options)
   at BLLayer.Common.Common.CreateXML(String toEmail, Int32& notificationCount, String& email, Boolean IsFirstTime)"
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception?  Also note that your exception handling is *throwing away* a lot of potentially useful information.

Comment: I am not getting any exception while debugging.

Errors comes when I install the setup. Then it creates Log file for exception.

Comment: I'm not even sure what you're trying to clarify with that comment.  Clearly an exception is being thrown, since you *posted an exception*.  The question is, *which line throws the exception*?  What is the *stack trace* for the exception?  Again, note that your code is *throwing away exception information*.  You might want to, you know, *not* throw away exception information.  And perhaps, you know, *keep it* somewhere so you can diagnose the problem.

Comment: I am just saving the exceptions in text file and not throwing those.

CreateXML() method throws exception but I cann't debug that because exception is not coming while debugging.

Comment: `"I am just saving the exceptions"` - No, you're just saving the exception *message* in a text file.  The rest of the information about the exception (such as the stack trace, for example, though some exception types can hold considerably more useful information) is being completely ignored.  You don't have to be able to replicate the error while debugging to *log* the error at runtime.  When an exception is thrown, you need to *at least* capture the exception type, error message, stack trace, originating line, and do this for any nested inner exceptions as well.

Comment: ok I Will save those and get back to you, Thanks

Comment: I have posted stack trace in my question. Hope this will helpful.

Comment: Try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11913904/close-instance-of-a-xdocument

Answer (score 1):

You may need to Close() the XDocument before you Load() it the second time.

Comment: @Gaurav123 `Using(XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(filePath))
{...}' It _close_ the object.,